# How does one run GNOME Shell in a window? (nested session)

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, wayland, development, xephyr

I am running GNOME Shell under Wayland and I would like to debug extensions in a nested session so that I don't have to restart the compositor, how can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
env GNOME_SHELL_SLOWDOWN_FACTOR=2 \ 
    MUTTER_DEBUG_DUMMY_MODE_SPECS=1024x768 \
    dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --nested \
                                    --wayland
```

[Source](https://youtu.be/YjMgtUSYg4w?t=1890)